# Running a command on a qemu terminal, and it asks for a login (autosar)

Tags: qemu, autosar

after running the command

runqemu qemux86 core-image-apd-devel nographic 
qemuparams="-net socket,mcast=224.244.224.245:30490"

The terminal then prompts for a

192.168.7.2 login:

and then asks for a password

Does anybody know where I could obtain these Login/Passwords from??
I am following these https://wiki.autosar.org/doku.php?id=apd_user_guide:run:qemu and https://wiki.autosar.org/doku.php?id=apd_user_guide:build:general links.

Comment: Enter user name as root.It wont ask for the password.

Comment: How to get an account of autosar wiki?